# New to Rails: How to Add New Functions to a Controller that Already Exists?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

One uses

```
rails generate controller ControllName function1 function2 etc
```

to generator a controller and functions with views for each function. Once the controller already exists, though, how would I use a similar command to add more functions and views automatically to the controller?

If I try the same generate code (with different method names) again, it wants to override the existing controller.

Comment: generators are really just for a quick and simple way to get started... they're not to be used *every* time you need a new method in your controller.  Just add another method and the view file manually

Answer (score 7):

The generators, as already mentioned in a comment, is just for getting started. If you want to add a new action (method/function), just go ahead and define it.

```
def my_action
  @things = Thing.all
  ...
end
```

Remember to map the new action in the config/routes.rb file. For example:

```
match '/my_action' => 'controllername#my_action', :as => 'my_action'
```

This will also give you the named routes `my_action_path` and `my_action_url`.